# UITableView Rows Height After Loading Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView` that contains 4 different types of customized cells in `storyboard`. Each cell has customized `UILabels` which get variable amount of text data from backend. I am struggling with making the cells resizing correctly. I would really want to change the height of each cell but I can not use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because it is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but the height is actually calculated within each customized cell.

I tried writing in each cells' height into an array while the `UITableView` is loading, then just reloading it all over again once, but no effect. I tried using `CGFloat rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` with no success either. The customized labels in each cell definitely grow with text which I see when I just statically change row height to higher numbers. So, I would need somehow my labels to push on rows to make them grow, not sure.

Different similar posts on stackoverflow that I found did not help.

Comment: post your code what u have tried

Comment: `UITableViewAutomaticDimension ` would make it, but probably u didnt pin top and bottom to the cell

Comment: Tried doing it, but somehow does not work. Sorry, can not post the code, it is proprietary.

Comment: I faced the same issue, use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in code and set proper constraints for the contents inside the cell, they will handle the cell height as per the top and bottom constraint values.

Comment: I set top and bottom constraints of the growing customized label to the table row, and set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and no success.

Comment: I tried setting them to `ContentView` instead and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to set up top and bottom constraints to the `ContentView` and NOT to the cell itself in the storyboard.

[image]

Label -> ContentView top and bottom constraints need to be set up. And then `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` specified in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

`estimatedRowHeight` should be set too. For example:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 76.0f;
```

Comment: estimatedRowHeight should be set too

Answer (score 0):

First Method called is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Second:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

set a break point in the above methods and test it. So if you want to preset the height use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`method.